# How do I send a email in Ionic 3 (Not using email composer)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, smtp

I am trying to `send out an email automatically` once I click a button in my **ionic 3 project**. Currently, I have all the information I need `(i.e. recipient email, subject, body) for the email`, but I don't know how to send it out automatically. Everyone says that `email composer` is the way to go but it doesn't meet my requirements. I need the emails to be sent automatically upon clicking a button **(without needing to open the email app to send the email manually).**

If possible, please provide some **guidelines/working examples** on how this can be done for free!

Comment: This usually cannot be done in Ionic itself. You would need to have a server doing that, or a cloud service. Zapier is a nice tool for email automation https://zapier.com/help/create/email-and-text-messages/send-emails-in-zaps

Comment: @Thimo Thanks for the recommendation. Are there any other suggestions for these external services? I don't think Zapier is free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out! I used **EmailJS** to send the email through my ionic 3 application.

https://www.emailjs.com/docs/sdk/installation/

This link helped me get started with EmailJS.

Answer (score 0):

Sending email through [NodeMailer](https://nodemailer.com/usage/) is quite easy. You can use it. I have used it and it has solved my problem.

Comment: Hello there. Thank you for your suggestion, but if I am not wrong, NodeMailer is not compatible with Ionic so I can't use that.

Comment: It's possible, because you will build an api with nodejs in which you can implement `nodemailer`. Just you need to call that api from Ionic, that's it.

Comment: Are there any existing tutorials on this? I have tried the existing tutorial from CodeForGeek (https://codeforgeek.com/send-e-mail-node-js/) and it doesn't work on my end in my ionic project. I can't seem to find the tutorial for calling the API from ionic either.

Answer (score 0):

You can full fill your requirement from server side all kind of things `(i.e. recipient email, subject, body)` you send to the server and server will handle that think to send an email.

You can make an api for email and call it from your app when user clicks on it.

here is link for send email from php

```
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp
```

Or if your api is in Node you can use this link

```
https://stackabuse.com/how-to-send-emails-with-node-js/
```